# Mysql - Update query with max of another column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to perform an update query with Max.
I am have 4 columns in my table - ID, Increase, FinalVal, Flag

My table is structure is:

```
Id  Increase    FinalVal    Flag
 1   0.1          30        null
 1   0.2          15        null
 2   0.1          15        null
 2   0.2          45        null
```

After I run the query the result should be:

```
 Id Increase    FinalVal    Flag
 1   0.1          30        1
 1   0.2          15        0
 2   0.1          15        0
 2   0.2          45        1
```

Flag should be updated to 1 for max(finalval) grouped by ID

I would really appreciate any help on this! Thanks

Comment: What is database are you using?

Comment: Final Value is just another column in the table. I am using sql server

Comment: Do you have an example of the SQL you've tried already?

Comment: No! I am not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

In most databases you can do:

```
update t
    set flag = (case when finalval = (select max(t2.finalval) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id)
                     then 1 else 0
                end);
```

Comment: Since id appears multiple times shouldn't i use group by in the select statement. select max(finalval) group by Id??

Comment: @PSnh . . . Not at all.  The correlation clause does what you need.